# Change directory to downloads

Tags: command-line, android, adb

I'm trying to get ADB up and going but having a bit of a hard time. In order to install Android SDK Tools I need to change directory and this is what I'm having a hard time doing. Here is what I'm getting in the terminal:

```
$ cd /downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools
bash: cd: /downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you download and extract the SDK. The download should have gone into the ~/Downloads folder and extracting should have created the ~/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools folder.

Answer (score 1):

The directory you're trying to change into doesn't exist.

This is probably what you want instead:

```
cd "$HOME/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools"
```

Notes:

- The `/` represents the root of your filesystem, **not** your home folder.
- Paths are case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the folder `downloads` in the root directory (unlikely) or was it `~/Downloads` as in Downloads with a capital D in the home directory? If you go to the folder in Nautilus and right click you can get to properties and in that the location is given.

Comment: This is what it said in the properties: Tpe: Folder (inode/directory) Location: /home/kendall